# image and text in a single line in button via css without float

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the image and text in the same line effect in a button. For other tags like div and p, display: inline works pretty fine but it doesn't seem to work for button tag. Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xfgjoo23/

The code:

```
<button>
    <span class="astext">
        Next
    </span><img src="image/delete1.png" class="del" style="width:10px;height:10px"  />
</button>
```

And my css:

```
 img.del {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 74%;
    position: relative;
    }
.astext {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
button {
    width: 80px;
}
```

Please note: I do want to use button tag and I know float: right will work but this is the last option because it looks pretty weird though ...

Comment: What you have basically works, but you're setting the margins so high that there's just not enough room for them both to fit, so the image gets wrapped to the next line. Either increase the width of the button, or decrease the margins between the span and img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin-right: 74%;` of `img.del` will effect it. Because it is too high. It will break the line.  Change it to `margin-left: 10px;  margin-right: 5%;`

```
img.del {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    position: relative;
    }
```

Will make it looks fine.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfgjoo23/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

`margin-right: 74%;` and `img` codes position made this happen.

just moved `img` tag to before span and delete `margin-right:74%;`

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xfgjoo23/2/

Answer (score 0):

delete both the `<span>` tag and `margin-right: 74%` will make them in the same line.

and if you add two `&nbsp` between the text and image will make it looks even better:

```css
img.del {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
    }
    .astext {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
    button {
        width: 80px;
    }
```

```html
<button>
    Next&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img src="image/delete1.png" class="del" style="width:10px;height:10px" />
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/xfgjoo23/3/

```
<button>
    <span class="astext">
        Next
    <img src="image/delete1.png" class="del" style="width:10px;height:10px"  /></span>
</button>
```

`css`

```
span img{height:100%;}
```

i think this is perfect way to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
<button >
    <img src="image/delete1.png" class="del" style="width:10px;height:10px"  />
    <span class="astext">
        Next
    </span>
</button>

 img.del {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    }
.astext {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
button {
    width: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```